# Merge Replication for new created tables

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, merge-replication

I have two SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard servers and they are using merge replication, sometimes new tables are created in the subscriber and I want it to be replicated to the publisher. 
Is there an option in SQL Server that allows me to replicate the new created table to the publisher or I have to make my custom procedure to do this.
If you have other suggestion (Like use something else other merge replication) you are welcome

**Note**: some clients are connected to the subscriber and others to the publisher and no I can't shift all the clients to the publisher.

Answer (score 0):

steps are the following:

1. Create the table on the publisher
2. Add the table to the publication (sp_addmerge... - I forgot!)
3. recreate the snapshot
4. restart subscription

The suscriber will then be updated with the latest additions in the snapshot: only the new table(s) will be sent to the suscriber.

It you still need some help ....